# fibonachi inside form

Tags: javascript

i have a case like this, when user input an numeric on the input, then the system will generate that number and sums it all,
example like this:

```
 <form action="" method="post">
  input here<br>
  <input type="text" id="input">

  <p>result here</p>
  <p id="result">
  </p>
  <button onclick="submit();">submit</button>
</form>


function submit(){
  var i;
  var a=document.getElementById('input').value;
  var fib = []; // Initialize array!
  fib[0] = 0;
  fib[1] = 1;
  for(i=2; i<=a; i++)
  {
      // Next fibonacci number = previous + one before previous
      // Translated to JavaScript:
      fib[i] = fib[i-2] + fib[i-1];
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = fib[i];

  }
}
```

when i press submit its got error like this

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x416fe10>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x3c36510>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x416fe10>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0x3c36590>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}
```

what is that?

Comment: why these numbers? why not 42?

Comment: We are not here to do your homework. What have you tried. It involves adding an event handler and using a for loop.

Comment: It's clearly a [Fibbonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). You'll just need to figure out how to generate Fibbonacci numbers and then generate N of them, where N is the value of your textbox.

Comment: @k102 that's Fibonacci.

Comment: @k102 it is a simple logic problem 1+1 = 2, 1 + 2 = 3, 2 + 3 = 5 ...

Comment: Fibbonacci that what its called. tq sir. i try to remember what its called

Comment: @nicael shame on me

Comment: update my description sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

```js
function fibo(number){
  var a=b=1;
  var output = [];
  if(number==1){
    output.push(1);
    }if(number==2){
    output.push(1,1);
    }else if(number >2){
      output.push(1,1);
      for(i=0;i<number-2;i++)  {
      temp = a+b;
      a =b;
        b=temp;
      output.push(temp);
      }
    }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =  output.join();
  }
```

```html
<input placehoder="Number of Fibonacci Elements" type="text" onchange="fibo(this.value);">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Select `No wrap head` after clicking on javascript link in fiddle